# Undesired output of series of numbers and letters for Dice Roll (Text based rpg) C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a small text rpg based on a dice roll system. However I keep getting a weird output of letter and numbers instead of the intended integer when I call the rollDice function.

PlayerCreation.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "Player.h"

void ChooseBuild();
void GenerateStats();
Player player;

int stats[5];

void PlayerCreation() {
    cout << "What is my name?" << endl;
    cin >> sOpt;
    player.setName(sOpt);

    cout << "Ah, yes my name is " << player.getName() << "! I don't remember this body though it's so..." << endl;
    ChooseBuild();
    GenerateStats();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        cout << stats << endl;
}

void ChooseBuild() {
//There is stuff here.
}

void GenerateStats() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        stats[i] = rollDice(12, 2) / 2;
}
```

rollDice.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

//Creates a random number which is then used to roll different dice.
default_random_engine random;
uniform_int_distribution<int> d4(1, 4);
uniform_int_distribution<int> d6(1, 6);
uniform_int_distribution<int> d8(1, 8);
uniform_int_distribution<int> d10(1, 10);
uniform_int_distribution<int> d12(1, 12);
uniform_int_distribution<int> d100(1, 100);
auto D4 = bind(d4, random);
auto D6 = bind(d6, random);
auto D8 = bind(d8, random);
auto D10 = bind(d10, random);
auto D12 = bind(d12, random);
auto D100 = bind(d100, random);

int rollDice(int die, int num) {
    int diceTotal = 0;
    if (die == 4) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            diceTotal += D4();
        }
    }
    if (die == 6) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            diceTotal += D6();
        }
    }
    if (die == 8) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            diceTotal += D8();
        }
    }
    if (die == 10) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            diceTotal += D10();
        }
    }
    if (die == 12) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            diceTotal += D12();
        }
    }
    if (die == 100) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            diceTotal += D100();
        }
    }
    return diceTotal;
}
```

It displays something like this:

```
000E63B0
000E63B0
000E63B0
000E63B0
000E63B0
```

Comment: Please make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay sorry, got rid of the irrelevant code and just kept the two pertinent files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stats is an array. So `cout << stats` prints address of the first element. You need a separate loop to iterate over `stats` elements and print each of them.

**Edit:** actually you have a loop already, just add index: `cout << stats[i-1] << endl;`

**Edit2:** also you have some errors w.r.t. array indexing: array `int stats[5];` has elements `stats[0]`, `stats[1]`, `stats[2]`, `stats[3]` and `stats[4]`; so to iterate other them use loop which starts at `0` and is strictly less than `5`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << stats[i] << endl;
```